# Scheduling some python tasks

Tags: python, scheduler

I am trying to schedule some tasks using python...
Here is the whole project:

I have online classes on zoom which I want to automatically record. (I can't wake up on time). I have the invite link to the meeting. The time and date of the meeting are mentioned in it.
I have written the python script to extract the message. Let's call this script A.

I have also written a script to click on the link so that the zoom meeting opens. Let's call this script B.

I need to run the scripts in this order:

1. I manually run script A at let's say 12:00 AM in the night(morning). By that time, the teachers would have sent the invite link message.
2. Based on the information that was extracted, I want to automatically run script B and start the OBS recording. A way to end the recording after the meeting has ended would also be appreciated. (or I could just record for 1 hour).

I just need to find a way to automatically start recording from OBS screen recorder at the time mentioned in the message. (possibly in script B only)

How do I go about it?

Comment: With questions like these, you should always mention which OS you're using. Some have built-in schedulers, others don't.

Comment: Windows 7 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [windows task scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler).

scriptA extracts the start time for the online task, sleeps until the correct time (using `time.sleep()`) and then uses `subprocess.Popen` to start script B at the appropriate time.

For example; simply starting script B, discarding any output (assuming it resides in the current working directory):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(
  ['python3', 'scriptB.py'],
  stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
  stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL
)
```

Comment: You could use the `schedule` module instead of `schtasks.exe`. But in both cases you will need `subprocess.Popen` to start script B.

Comment: Could you provide me with some sample code because I am having difficulty understanding how to use subprocess and schtasks.exe together...

Comment: Or is there a tutorial you could recommend?